# How to loop through all subject names if subject name contains special Characters that are not matching in soup

Tags: python, web, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, find

1. This code generates attribute Error because it doesn't match with subjects in web page due to special characters in Subject name.
2. Provide any solution for the following code if subject changes

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv

seat = ""
total = ""
remarks = ""
percentage = ""
subjects = ["MANAGEMENT","PROGRAMMING WITH PYTHON","MOBILE APPLICATION DEVELOPMENT","EMERGING TRENDS IN COMPUTER AND INFORMATION TECHNOLGY","NETWORK AND INFORMATION SECURITY","ENTERPRENURESHIP DEVELOPMENT","CAPSTONE PROJECT EXECUTION & REPORT WRITTING"]

marks = []
start = 302060
end = 302065
for seat_number in range(start,end):
    URL = "https://msbte.org.in/DISRESLIVE2021CRSLDSEP/COV6139QS21LIVEResult/SeatNumber/30/"+str(seat_number)+"Marksheet.html"
    r = requests.get(URL)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content,'html.parser')
    
    name=soup.find_all('table')[0].find_all('tr')[0].find_all('td')[1].text

    seat = soup.find('td',text="SEAT NO.").find_next('td').text
    marks.append(seat)
    #name_of Student
    marks.append(name)
```

3. Below part of code generates error it does not works for all the subjects

```
    for subject in subjects:
        var=soup.find('td',text=subject)
        for i in range(36):
            if subject=="PROGRAMMING WITH PYTHON" or subject=="MOBILE APPLICATION DEVELOPMENT" or subject=="NETWORK AND INFORMATION SECURITY":
                if(i==5):
                    marks.append(var.text)
                if(i==14):
                    marks.append(var.text)
                if(i==23):
                    marks.append(var.text)
                if(i==32):
                    marks.append(var.text)
                var = var.find_next('td')
            else:
                if(i==5):
                    marks.append(var.text)
                if(i==14):
                    marks.append(var.text)
                var = var.find_next('td')

    #for getting total,percentage,remarks
    total = soup.find_all('table')[2].find_all('tr')[1].find_all('td')[2].text
    percentage = soup.find_all('table')[2].find_all('tr')[1].find_all('td')[1].text
    remarks = soup.find_all('table')[2].find_all('tr')[2].find_all('td')[1].text
    sub=soup.find_all('table')[1].find_all('tr')[2].find_all('td')[0].text
    #print(sub)
#    sub
    marks.append(total)
    marks.append(percentage)
    marks.append(remarks)
    #add to the excel sheet
    with open("C:\\sem6.csv", 'a', newline='') as f:
        w = csv.writer(f)
        w.writerow(marks)
    del marks[:]
```

Comment: Please can you [edit] your question to explain what and how the script is trying to extract from the page. It would then help to understand why it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

The subject that is not matching is actually `CAPSTONE PROJECT –EXECUTION & REPORT WRITING`, but you could compare just the start of each subject for a match.

It might also be easier to parse the table rows once in order and use a `defaultdict(list)` to store each subject as you find it. The same dictionary could then be used to hold all of your other values such as `Name` and `Seat`.

A `csv.DictWriter()` could then be used to write the output CSV file. For example:

```
from collections import defaultdict
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import csv

subjects = ["MANAGEMENT", "PROGRAMMING WITH PYTHON", "MOBILE APPLICATION DEVELOPMENT", "EMERGING TRENDS IN COMPUTER AND INFORMATION TECHNOLGY", "NETWORK AND INFORMATION SECURITY", "ENTERPRENURESHIP DEVELOPMENT", "CAPSTONE PROJECT -EXECUTION & REPORT WRITTING"]
                                                                                                                                                                              
start = 302060
end = 302065
csv_output = None       # Delay until header is known

with open('output.csv', 'w', newline='') as f_output:

    for seat_number in range(start, end):
        marks = defaultdict(list)
        
        URL = f"https://msbte.org.in/DISRESLIVE2021CRSLDSEP/COV6139QS21LIVEResult/SeatNumber/30/{seat_number}Marksheet.html"
        r = requests.get(URL)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser', from_encoding="utf-8")
        all_tables = soup.find_all('table')
        marks['Name'] = all_tables[0].find_all('tr')[0].find_all('td')[1].text
        marks['Seat'] = soup.find('td', text="SEAT NO.").find_next('td').text
        print(f"Name: {marks['Name']}  Seat: {marks['Seat']}")
        current_subject = None
        
        for tr in all_tables[1].find_all('tr'):
            row = [td.get_text(strip=True) for td in tr.find_all('td')]

            if row[0] == '' or any(row[0].startswith(subject[:10]) for subject in subjects):
                if row[0]:
                    current_subject = row[0]
                
                if current_subject:
                    marks[current_subject].append(int(row[5]))
                    
        #for getting total,percentage,remarks
        marks['Total'] = all_tables[2].find_all('tr')[1].find_all('td')[2].text
        marks['Percentage'] = all_tables[2].find_all('tr')[1].find_all('td')[1].text
        marks['Remarks'] = all_tables[2].find_all('tr')[2].find_all('td')[1].text
    
        if not csv_output:
            csv_output = csv.DictWriter(f_output, fieldnames=marks.keys())
            csv_output.writeheader()
    
        csv_output.writerow(marks)
```

This approach reads the main table a row at time and extracts the 6th entry from each row into the appropriate subject entry.

It would give you an output CSV file starting:

```
Name,Seat,MANAGEMENT,PROGRAMMING WITH PYTHON,MOBILE APPLICATION DEVELOPMENT,EMERGING TRENDS IN COMPUTER AND INFORMATION TECHNOLGY,NETWORK AND INFORMATION SECURITY,ENTERPRENURESHIP DEVELOPMENT,CAPSTONE PROJECT –EXECUTION & REPORT WRITING,Total,Percentage,Remarks
KHARAT AKASH CHANDRAKANT,302060,"[58, 22]","[66, 22, 21, 20]","[64, 22, 20, 20]","[54, 18]","[70, 27, 20, 20]","[40, 42]","[37, 41]",704,82.82,FIRST CLASS DIST.  
MORE AMRUTA TUKARAM,302061,"[34, 16]","[48, 12, 13, 12]","[50, 10, 22, 18]","[38, 5]","[64, 21, 12, 12]","[39, 42]","[31, 41]",540,63.53,FIRST CLASS
```